# Are there any countermeasures to turbo-controller users?

Tags: naruto-ultimate-ninja-storm-2

I've been playing quite a few online matches of Ultimate Ninja Storm 2 and have come across quite a few people who use a turbo controller to gain an unfair advantage.

Seeing how blocking just before an attack hits allows you to perform a substitution jutsu, negating all damage and placing you behind your attacker, people that use a turbo controller to spam the guard button are nigh-impossible to attack, as any attack in the game can be avoided in this manner.

This also allows them to land rather potent attacks while their opponent is still recovering from the sudden reversal, which in turn gives them breathing room to recharge their chakra (which is necessary to perform substitution jutsu).

Ranged characters may be a good counter to this technique, as substitution jutsu does not place you behind the attacker if he is not within melee range, but it is impossible to spot a turbo-controller user at the character selection stage.

Is there any tactic I can use to punish people who rely on turbo blocking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After playing quite a few online matches, I am afraid there seems to be no definitive solution for facing people who use turbo-enabled controllers (CyberConnect2 seem to be trying to remedy this in their new game, [Ultimate Ninja Storm Generations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naruto_Shippuden:_Ultimate_Ninja_Storm_Generations), by adding a substitution jutsu bar to limit the use of substitution jutsu). There are, however, a few tips that can help you increase your chances of winning significantly.

The key to beating a turbo-controller user is playing defensively, with an emphasis on the following:

- Keeping your distance
- Taking advantage of your opponent's mistakes

This is most easily done by pressuring your opponent with shuriken, causing him to waste some chakra by using substitution unnecessarily. Eventually, your opponent will probably try to close the distance by rushing you, which is your opportunity to deal some damage with a jutsu or ultimate jutsu. This could be done even more easily with a ranged character such as Shino, though I personally use Shikamaru as his chakra shuriken has knockback and are very useful at keeping your opponent at bay.

Still, all the above doesn't really help if you are facing someone that is using a turbo controller and is actually good. Such opponents actually use turbo-blocking with a degree of sense and don't simply use substitution on any attack. I've seen some people use turbo-blocking coupled with enough aggression that you hardly have enough time to think before they annihilate you.

Answer (score 2):

They spam block? You spam grab.

Figure out some damaging moves once they are on the ground, or use that time to build chakra.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can substitution out of a grab (something I find rather outrageous, as you can't block a grab) and the only thing that you can hit a downed opponent with are shuriken (and those can actually trigger a substitution, allowing a faster recovery...)

Answer (score 1):

There are really only two things you can do.  First, file a bug report with the developers, (who ought to be able to write some code to detect and respond to turbo controller usage if they decide it shouldn't be done,) and second, don't play with people who use turbo controllers.

Comment: -1. You didn't answer the question. Filing bug reports, and not playing with someone(how do you avoid playing with them in random online matches?) is not the same thing as countering the use of turbo controllers.

Comment: @attack but is there any other option? This might be the only one.

Comment: @AttackingHobo: Yeah, basically what Jeff said. It doesn't look like this question has gathered any other answers. I've done some work on game engine creation, and this really feels to me like something that can't be "fixed" on the user's end.

Comment: i agree, non-standard controllers are used in shooters ( CoD etc. ) and they are classified as cheating. You should report the players, which in turn could get them banned.